# In Fish, how do I check that two paths are the same?

Tags: fish

I'm trying to write an if statement that checks to see if two variables refer to the same file or directory. I can't simply compare the strings, because I want two different strings that refer to the same path.

For example, I would like to check if `./` and `../foobar/` refer to the same directory.

Simply doing `test "$path1" -eq "$path2"` won't work in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found in [the documentation for the `test` command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/test.html):

> #### Operators to compare files and directories
>
> *FILE1* -ef *FILE1*
>
> Returns true if *FILE1* and *FILE2* refer to the same file.

Here's an example:

```
 if test "$path1" -ef "$path2"
      echo "These two variables refer to the same file"
 end
```

Note that the two paths have to refer to a file or directory that exists. If `foobar` does not exist, then `test foobar -ef foobar` will evaluate to false.